# Using kable function with cbind or other methods to select variables

Tags: r-markdown

In R Markdown, I wrote a chunk to print correlation of selected variables contained in a larger file, using cbind. This works within R Markdown, but when I try to knit it I get "Error in cbind(LS1, LS2, LS3, MF1, MF2) : object 'LS1' not found calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cbind Execution halted.

```
mydata <- readRDS("mydata4knit.rds")
ZZ <- cbind(LS1, LS2, LS3, MF1, MF2)
kable(round(cor(ZZ),2)[1:5, ], caption = "Correlation of mydata.")
```

What is the correct way to use cbind to select variables when using the kable function? Thank you!

Comment: When you knit, the code is run in another R session. This requires all variables used to be declared inside the Rmd. 
Where does variable LS1 comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

Sébastien,

Your response helped me to figure how to pass the data from R to Markdown:

```
 source('Factor-Analysis-Test-Data_Only.R')
```

```
kable(round(cor(X2),2)[1:5, ], caption = "Correlation of mydata.")
```

X2 <- cbind(LS1, LS2, LS3, MF1, MF2) defined in my R file.

Merci!